# AttributeError: ImageClip instance has no attribute 'mode'

Tags: python, matplotlib, attributeerror, moviepy

I am trying to extract frames from a video based on time, plot some x and y coordinate value data on each frame and combine the frames into a video again using `moviepy`. I used this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29974472/difficulty-animating-a-matplotlib-graph-with-moviepy) as a reference for plotting data on the extracted frames. I am using this [video](http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4) for testing. Below is the code that I am running:

```
from moviepy.editor import *
from moviepy.Clip import *
from moviepy.video.io.bindings import PIL_to_npimage
from moviepy.video.VideoClip import DataVideoClip
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import moviepy.editor as mpy

video = VideoFileClip("N:\SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.mp4")
audio1 = video.audio

t = np.arange(0, video.duration, (1/video.fps))
images_list = []

for i, n in enumerate(t):
    a = video.get_frame(n)
    clip = ImageClip(a)
    path = "C:\\Users\\Naveen\\Desktop\\frame\\frame" + str(i) + ".png"
    clip.save_frame(path)
    images_list.append(path)

x = np.random.randn(10, 1)
y = np.random.randn(10, 1)
p = plt.plot(x, y, 'kx')
i = 0

def data_to_frame(time):
    global i
    xn = x + np.sin(2 * np.pi * time / 10.0)
    yn = y + np.cos(2 * np.pi * time / 8.0)
    p[0].set_data(xn, yn)
    image = ImageClip(images_list[i])
    f = PIL_to_npimage(image)
    i += 1
    return f

animate = DataVideoClip(t, data_to_frame, fps=1)
animate.write_videofile("test2.mp4", fps=15)
```

This is the error I get when I run the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "h.py", line 37, in <module>
    animate = DataVideoClip(t, data_to_frame, fps=1)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\moviepy-0.2.2.11-py2.7.egg\moviepy\video\VideoClip.py", line 814, in __init__
    duration=1.0*len(data)/fps, has_constant_size=has_constant_size)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\moviepy-0.2.2.11-py2.7.egg\moviepy\video\VideoClip.py", line 106, in __init__
    self.size = self.get_frame(0).shape[:2][::-1]
  File "<decorator-gen-14>", line 2, in get_frame
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\moviepy-0.2.2.11-py2.7.egg\moviepy\decorators.py", line 89, in wrapper
    return f(*new_a, **new_kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\moviepy-0.2.2.11-py2.7.egg\moviepy\Clip.py", line 95, in get_frame
    return self.make_frame(t)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\moviepy-0.2.2.11-py2.7.egg\moviepy\video\VideoClip.py", line 812, in <lambda>
    make_frame = lambda t: self.data_to_frame( self.data[int(self.fps*t)])
  File "h.py", line 33, in data_to_frame
    f = PIL_to_npimage(image)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\moviepy-0.2.2.11-py2.7.egg\moviepy\video\io\bindings.py", line 11, in PIL_to_npimage
    d = (4 if im.mode=="RGBA" else 3)
AttributeError: ImageClip instance has no attribute 'mode'
```

The problem here is that I don't know the right way to import the frames into the function `PIL_to_npimage`. Or rather, the question here should be, how to import an image as an image in `moviepy`. Also, there should be no axis lines in the final video. I want to be able to plot only the data.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and include the full traceback?  The line you've given isn't in your code anywhere so it's difficult to know where the error is coming from.

Comment: @LukeWoodward I have edited the question to include the full traceback. The error is coming from the function `PIL_to_npimage`. Here is the [function](http://pydoc.net/Python/moviepy/0.2.1.9.07/moviepy.video.io.bindings/)